# WordPress 3.5: Setting custom "full URL path to files" in the Media Library?

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

As the recent changes in WordPress 3.5 removed the "full URL path to files" option from media library I am wondering how to set this option to a custom path now?

I need to set my "full URL path to files" for my media files to a custom subdomain. Can you guys help me out with finding a solution for this problem?

Regards,
faxxim

Comment: Hello I wrote a small plugin for the new facilities Wordpress 3.5.
You can directly modify the domain or subdomain
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-original-media-path/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The option name is `upload_url_path`, and you can still filter it:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_upload_url_path', 'wpse_77960_upload_url' );

function wpse_77960_upload_url()
{
    return 'http://subdomain.example.com/files';
}
```

Comment: remove trailing slash because you will have double slashes in the url, like `'http://subdomain.example.com/files//path/to/image.jpg'`

Comment: OK, good to know its that easy! Thank you very much!

Comment: @EugeneManuilov Forgot that. Fixed. :) Most system treat double slashes in the middle of a path like a single slash.

Comment: @toscho I know that it will work, but it is not feng shui to have double slashes :)

Comment: @EugeneManuilov That’s why I remove those [per .htaccess](http://toscho.de/2009/wordpress-2-8-3-das-doppelslash-problem/).

Comment: @toscho nice stuff, voted up

Comment: Why is it not enough to use the constant `UPLOADS` ? Is it realy the wish in the question, that you define the full url?

Comment: @bueltge `UPLOADS` is a file path, `upload_url` is an URL. Two different URLs can point to the same local path, and there is no way to determine the correct URL for a given path. So both are two different things.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you @Toscho for providing me with the name of the option. Here's another way to change it, by placing this in your functions.php file:

```
update_option('upload_url_path', '/wp-content/uploads');
```

This will make WordPress embed images like `src="/wp-content/uploads/file.jpg"` instead of `src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/file.jpg"`