# Change URLs for static content

Tags: uploads, media-library

My host has a high speed NGINX cluster.

I'd like to load my CSS, JS and media files from this cluster. I've followed [these steps](https://www.tsohost.com/knowledge-base/article/495/speed-up-serving-static-content) and added the new static domain via my DNS.

The new DNS settings have propagated successfully and I can access my static files like so http://static.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css.

To begin with, I would like to change the media upload URL. I have tried to add the following snippet to `wp-config.php` before  `require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);`

```
/** Path to NGINX cluster */
define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'http://static.example.com/wp-content/uploads' );
```

When saving the above snippet to `wp-config.php` and refreshing the site, my media files (images) are loading from the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/http://static.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/image-name.jpg
```

As you can see, the root URL is loading before the static URL. What's the correct way to set the new upload path? Should I also perform a search and replace for the previous uploads?

I also assume that I change my JS and CSS paths in `functions.php`, like so?:

```
// Before
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array(), '20161025', false );

// After
wp_enqueue_script('script', 'http://static.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/js/script.js', array(), '20161025', false );
```

Comment: Looks like it assumes uploads is a folder. Maybe you could filter the output somehow to use another URL

Comment: Thank you @jgraup. Your comment prompted further investigation and I found the below answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77960/wordpress-3-5-setting-custom-full-url-path-to-files-in-the-media-library) has solved the problem.

You need to add this to your `functions.php` file.

```
/**
* Custom media upload URL
* @link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77960/wordpress-3-5-setting-custom-full-url-path-to-files-in-the-media-library
*/
add_filter( 'pre_option_upload_url_path', 'upload_url' );

function upload_url() {
    return 'http://static.yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads';
}
```

There's no need to add the original snippet to `wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to tell WordPress to use a sub domain (or another domain) by defining a globals variable in your config.php file.

```
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://static.yourdomain.com');
```

Put this at the very beginning of the config file otherwise it may not work. This  will update the url of all resource in wp-content directory.

> Read more about it on [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Constants)

Comment: This may break some plugins (eg. Yoast SEO). If you intend to use it for CDN, it's best to use a cache plugin that allows you to set a CDN url.